# How to center div with different sizes on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a "modal" and everything works fine except for the first time I open a new modal window, it does not appear in the center of the page. After I open a modal for the first time then all the windows appear centered on the screen.

HTML:

```
<div id="modal3" class="galleryContent">
    <div class="modalheader">
        <h3>Imagen 2</h3>
        <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contenidomodal">
        <p>La imagen número 1 reprensta al profesor Sebastian.</p>
        <img src="img/copy_mcrepeatsalot.png" alt="Sebastian">
    </div>
    <div class="modalfooter">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

> ```
>   <script>
>       var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>')
>       $("body").append($overlay);
>
>       $(document).ready(function(){
>
>           $("#imageGallery a").click(function(event){
>               event.preventDefault();
>               var $target = $(this).attr("data-target");
>               var $altura = $(".galleryContent").height();
>               var $anchura = $(".galleryContent").width();
>
>               $(".galleryContent").css("margin-top", - $altura/2);
>               $(".galleryContent").css("margin-left", - $anchura/2);
>
>               $overlay.fadeIn();
>               $($target).fadeIn();
>
>               $("#overlay").click(function(){
>                   $($target).fadeOut();
>                   $overlay.fadeOut();
>               });
>
>               $(".fa-close").click(function(){
>                   $($target).fadeOut();
>                   $overlay.fadeOut();
>               });
>
>               $(".modalfooter button").click(function(){
>                   $($target).fadeOut();
>                   $overlay.fadeOut();
>               });
>           });
>       });
>   </script>
> ```

the variable $altura and $anchura = height and width are inside the click function so It takes the width and height of the current object.

Thanks.

Comment: please provide a fiddle, or at least the rest of the css, etc.

Comment: my guess is because you are using images perhaps the content hasn't finished loading for calculations.

Comment: That's what i thought. I can't give it a constant size because sometimes it can be smaller.

Comment: what you are trying to do is standard lightbox behavior. do you need to reinvent the wheel? I think there are 30 million implementations already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the assets inside your modal element fully load, your element's width/height will change, therefore your calculations will be wrong.

A long time ago I created something similar and had to insert a placeholder image into the modal's content. Then I changed that placeholder's **src** attribute for every image that I wanted to show. However, before displaying the modal I waited for the image to load. Here are some links to that project:

- https://github.com/vasilionjea/jQuery-Ezbox--v0.0.3-/blob/master/ezbox.js#L73
- https://github.com/vasilionjea/jQuery-Ezbox--v0.0.3-/blob/master/ezbox.js#L164

If you are supporting only modern Browsers though, you can center a block level element only with CSS. Here is an example of that:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/rawomasaqo/1/edit?css,output

Comment: Btw I also thought about inserting the image based on the clicked link but I didn't know how to do it, I'll be reading your code

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when you call .height() the content is not yet rendered and sized. You'll want to do that when fadeIn is complete, or at least started. Alternately, using `margin: auto;` usually works for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yea that's what I tought but I can't give it a constant size because sometimes the window can be smaller

Comment: You could use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to set breakpoints on width.